# Swift 4 to Swift 5 by applying the recommended changes

Tags: swift

I am currently upgrading Swift 4 to Swift 5 and Xcode recommended the following changes. However, I am wondering if that affect any logic that I implemented in Swift 4.

```
extension JSONDecoder {
  
  static let convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder: JSONDecoder = {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    return decoder
  }()
}

struct CustomError: Codable {
  let errors: [String]
}

private func decodeCustomError(data: Data, statusCode: Int) -> CustomError?  {
  if let errorData = try? JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data) as CustomError? {
    if let errorData = errorData {
       return formCustomError(jsonError)
    }
    return formCustomError(parsingError)
  } else if let errorMessage = State(rawValue: statusCode) {
    return formCustomError(errorMessage)
  } else {
    return formCustomError(genericError)
  }
}
```

**Swift 4 (Current Implementation)**

```
if let customError = try? JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data) as CustomError?
```

**Swift 5 (Recommended Change)**

```
if let customError = ((try? JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data) as CustomError?) as CustomError??)
```

Shall I safely assume these are same?

Comment: The original code looks strange to me, why the need for a cast?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have added the missing piece to the code. I would love to hear your valuable suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type cast is not needed at all, in Swift 5 possible double optionals are flattened

```
if let customError = try? JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data) {

}
```

However it's highly recommended to always handle (at least `print`) a potential error

```
do {
    let customError = try JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data)
    // do something with the error
} catch { print(error) }
```

Edit:

The method `decodeCustomError` with `do - catch` block is

```
private func decodeCustomError(data: Data, statusCode: Int) -> CustomError  {
   do {
       return try JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data)      
   } catch {
       if let errorMessage = State(rawValue: statusCode) {
          return formCustomError(errorMessage)
       } else {
          return formCustomError(error) // assuming `formCustomError` accepts an `Error` argument
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for providing detailed answer and suggestion. I have added the missing piece to give you a better picture where I am struggling. I have added the missing method `decodeCustomError`, I wonder how I could be able to fit into `do catch` statement as you suggested since I have several other scenario.

Comment: The `{` needs to be deleted, right?      `let customError = try JSONDecoder.convertFromSnakeCaseDecoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data)   {`

Comment: It is, reload the page, and you can `return` the decoded object directly.

Comment: Also, I do not see the following  `return formCustomError(parsingError)`, is there a way to handle somewhere `parsingError`?

Comment: It's unclear what `formCustomError` actually is but instead of `formCustomError(genericError)` return the parsing error (the implicit `error` instance in the `catch` block) or return the stuff in a different order.